# MVC Request - Core .NET - Non HTML Response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm new to Core.NET and would greatly appreciate some enlightenment.

I've watched many PluralSight videos, and have Core .NET book 'Pro ASP.NET Core MVC'.

All very well cover Routing / Controller Initialization / Action Method Execution / Action Result / View Engine.  I'm hung up on the Non HTML Response though.  (Please see image below)

[image]

In Traditional ASP.NET if I wanted to call some class that did something and returned no value, I'd simply:

```
    //  Call Twilio class that sends a test message
        TwilioRest Send_Test_SMS = new TwilioRest();
        Send_Test_SMS.testSMS_Send();
```

**My question is:**

1. How do I call the above class's function from the controller.
2. When adding a controller or when modifying a controller for that - do I need to alter or add something to the Startup.cs file

The course materials I have do a great job at covering returning HTML views - such as:

```
    //------book examples below-----
    public IActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult About()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }
```

But I feel like an idiot trying to do something so simple and would appreciate some insight into this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "How do I call the above class's function from the controller." Same way as you call any code. Add a reference to the DLL/namespace, if necessary, and then write the code to call the method. As for the other question I haven't done much with Core so I'm not sure on that. But it's not clear how either of these questions relate to your concern about Non-HTML responses? Such responses might reasonably be anticipated to be things like JSON, XML, text or binary file data.

Comment: 1. Add the code into a controller method and call via a url (It's that simple). 2. You don't need to do anything apart from recompiling.

Comment: Hi Steve - so on the above public IActionResult Index() method of the controller I could remove return View() and I'm trying to call a class in the project - so I'm confused by the "call via a url" portion of your answer.

Comment: Hi Sherman. I suggest you take a look on this link and when you are done, feel free to follow up with new questions. :) [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting)

Comment: @Sherman IActionResult can return various things and not always a view e.g. FileResult, JsonResult what you return is really dependant on what you expect back. You can for example change the signature of public IActionResult About() to public JsonResult About(). The calling by url part I meant for example http://localhost/home/about to call the controller method.

Comment: @Steve - Wow, now I get it, thank you

Comment: @Steve, thanks, now I'm getting it!! Appreciate your help!!

Comment: @Sherman No problem, glad it helped..

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure whether I got your point, but I guess you want to do sth like that:

```
//------book examples below-----
public IActionResult Index()
{
    //  Call Twilio class that sends a test message
    TwilioRest Send_Test_SMS = new TwilioRest();
    Send_Test_SMS.testSMS_Send();

    return Ok(); // Similiar meaning as => return StatusCode(200);
}
```

It's up to your design / contract which status code you want to return here you can find a list of http codes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

So to summarize you don't need to return 'HTML response', but obviously 'HTTP response'  must be returned.

If I misunderstood you then apologize.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your example and time, take care :-)